# Disable button until required fields are valid

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, form-submit

I've searched for the answer to this problem but still can't get this to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#contact_subject').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#contact_subject').val().length   >   0  {
        $('button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
       $('button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}

</script>
```

I want to make sure `#contact_subject` has data or else disable the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the event.Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/e0t7qv56/1/

```
$("#field").keyup(function(){
    console.log($(this).val().length);
    if($(this).val().length)
        $("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
    else
        $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: this will work also, for real time enabling of the button without clicking in another field for it to enable. Do i just add commas for it to take multiple conditions right? like:

`$("#field, #field2, #field3").keyup(function(){
    console.log($(this).val().length);
    if($(this).val().length)
        $("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
    else
        $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
});`

Comment: it didnt work for multiple fields...guess id have to put in an Or there or something

Comment: Thanks you awesome guy, will put this into production.

Comment: Please read more code, not only mine. I suppouse you're not much experienced at least on jQuery, you'd be surprised all that [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) can do

Comment: Yh you're right Junior Dev here. I know sp,e jquery just not all that much, thanks surely will.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are missing a bracket ) in if condition

```
function validate(){
    if ($('#contact_subject').val().length   >   0)  {
        $('button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
       $('button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. There normally comes a tick just below the votes. Might be some issue. Not a problem. Thanks for reverting.