# Here i wanted to verify the data entered by user and restrict him if data is not reaching all the requirements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As i'am new to JavaScript and jquery and want to validate some of the form fields on client side which was going good, but the problem is i don't want to send the data of form fields if any of one contains any error to the server. So how to restrict it, please do the need,thank you

Comment: http://www.formvalidator.net/ might help you

Comment: thank you, but i am in middle of spring project so i didn't get how to use or replace the code in my project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable button until required fields are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008849/disable-button-until-required-fields-are-valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways.

1) Use onSubmit callback with `return` (if true - submit; else - no submit)

```
<form onSubmit="return isValid(this)">

</form>
```

2) Use js onSubmit event and hijack form submitting.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function () {
    if (isValid(this)) {
        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.post('http://dev.null', data);
    }
    return false; // prevent natural from submitting
})
```

---

Example:

```js
function validate() {
  var form = $('#myForm');
  var input = $('#num');
  
  if (parseInt(input.val()) == 5) {
    form.removeClass('invalid');
    return true;
  } else {
    form.addClass('invalid');
    return false;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function () {
    console.log('onSubmit fired.', 'form data object:', $(this).serialize());
  });
})
```

```css
.invalid label {
  color: red;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = "myForm" action="/save.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
  <label>
    Enter number. <i>Only 5 is valid.</i><br/>
    <input type="number" id="num" name="number"/>
  </label>
  <label>
    This one has no effect, because no name attribute<br/>
    <input type="number" id="num2"/>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Seriously don't know what u talking about, bro i'am really new to js and jquery so what exactly serialize and $.post() are doing there...

Comment: @nasir Well, then google it. `.serialize()` converts all your form inputs data to proper HTTP format to send using `$.post` (alias for $.ajax)

Comment: thank you man,really helped me to get to the point and i'am overwhelmed for your concern..!!!

Comment: @nasir Don't forget to accept answer if it answers your question

Answer (score -1):

You can use   [bootstrap form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation) validation